# Using get_pages() in wordpress is stripping out my <p> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I use `get_pages()` to fetch the title and content of each of my top level pages and displays it on one page. Unfortunately it's stripping out all of my `<p>` tags and I'm not sure why. If the `<p>` tag has a style or class to it, it will keep it, but all normal `<p>` tags get stripped. Here is my code:

```
 <?php 
  $pages = get_pages('parent=0'); 
  foreach ($pages as $pagg) {
    $option = '<div class="section">';
    $option .= $pagg->post_title;
    $option .= $pagg->post_content;
    $option .= '</div>';
    echo $option;
  }
 ?>
```

EDIT:Alex was nice enough to provide the answer. The Solution below.

```
 <?php
  $pages = get_pages('parent=0'); 
  foreach ($pages as $pagg) {
    $option = '<div class="section">';
    $option .= $pagg->post_title;
    $option .= wpautop($pagg->post_content);
    $option .= '</div>';
    echo $option;
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not like `p` elements for some reason. Its WYSIWYG editor never (or rarely) inserts them.

Run the string through [`wpautop()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) to add the `p` elements.

Comment: Ah, wpautop(), of course. It took me a few tries to fix it in the proper syntax, but I got it. I'll update the question with the answer. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer below, I think its the 'proper' way of doing this. Its not related to p tags.

Comment: @addedlovely If the *wrong* output was missing `p` tags, how is it not related to them?

Comment: Because the whole content is not getting filtered, it then doesn't display how a normal call to the_content() would. It's more than just P tags, that's all I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the content.

```
apply_filters('the_content', $pagg->post_content);
```

This will return formatted text, shortcodes that are processed and omebeds that work.

This would happen automatically if you called setup_postdata(), or used the content from the loop.